# Condense jQuery hide/show scripts for page with multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, show-hide, multiple-instances, minify

I'm building a page that's going to have several select boxes that will reveal specific links based on the value selected. I can show/hide everything just fine, but I know I'm doing things the hard way. I'm still very new to JS/jQuery so I'm not sure how to condense my scripts to a single function (which I'm sure is possible).

#### Working jquery:

```
$('.trqVerSelect').change(function () {
  $('.trqVersions .links').hide();
  $('.ver' + $(this).val()).show();
}).change();

$('.mwmVerSelect').change(function () {
  $('.mwmVersions .links').hide();
  $('.ver' + $(this).val()).show();
}).change();
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paGhk/) showing that the above works. What I don't want is to build a ton of these functions for every single select box instance on the page - of which there will be 12 or so.

I tried the code below and it kind of works, but it hides all other selections whenever you make a new one. I want the user to be able to retain other selections when making a new selection in a different select box.

```
$('select').change(function () {
  $('.links').hide();
  $('.ver' + $(this).val()).show();
}).change();
```

Comment: Can you rename the classnames? What type of changes can you apply to your layout?

Comment: Yes, everything can be modified. That was just the framework I started with for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your HTML structure or using extra classes (like I did in the previous version of this answer), you could do something like this:

```
$('.component').each(function(){
  var $component = $(this);
  $component.find('select').on('change', function(){
    $component.find('.links').hide();
    $component.find('.ver' + $(this).val()).show();
  }).change();
});
```

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/paGhk/4/

Comment: There's value in this answer as well as the previous one. In this case, this script should still work even if I have to modify one of the components so the HTML structure doesn't flow the exact same way as the others components do.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't rely on the order of the objects, and doesn't require any extra classes or identifiers.  You might be able to refine this a bit more...  If I do, I'll update the answer.

Comment: This is working beautifully and is robust enough to still work even with variations in the HTML structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, http://jsfiddle.net/paGhk/1/

```
$('select').change(function () {
  $(this).parent().next().children().hide().filter(".ver" + $(this).val()).show();
}).change();
```

explained:

```
$('select').change(function () {
  $(this)  // <select />
    .parent() // <div />
    .next()  // <div />
    .children() // <p /><p />
    .hide() // hide them both
    .filter(".ver" + $(this).val()) // select the one with correct ver class
    .show(); // show it
}).change();
```

Comment: This seems to work so far, thanks for the explanation too! I'm going to do some more testing with it in my production environment and if it holds up there I'll mark as answer. Thanks!

Comment: I chose the other answer because I believe it to be more robust and seems to account for slight variations in HTML structure for different components. However, I learned a lot from this answer - just wanted you to know that. Thanks for the help :)